# What is the best way to account for some events in an input field?

Tags: javascript

Nested if statements for checking whether the fields are empty or complying with other parameters

```
   if (Name != '' && age != '') {
    if(age >= 18)
    alert("Successfully Submitted!"); 

    else
    alert("you must be over 18 :(");
    }

    else
    alert("cant be empty :(");
```

how do i check for individual fields with multiple parameters and respond accordingly for each event without having to nest a million if statements?

Comment: This is not really a concrete question, is it? // on the other hand if you have working code use [codereview.se], although read their help center before asking.

Comment: @user202729 I know. I don't know what I'm looking for exactly so it's hard. Just looking for better ways to implement things.

Answer (score 1):

Nested if statements are one of the ways, another way however is with **guard clauses**:

**References**

1. Agile Actors #learning

   - [Guard Clauses](https://learningactors.com/javascript-guard-clauses-how-you-can-refactor-conditional-logic/)
2. barker.codes

   - [Guard Clauses](https://barker.codes/blog/guard-clauses-in-javascript)

**My Explanation**

Basically, rather than using nested if statements to do certain things depending on the data, we can have a function. Within this function, we can have single if statements and **if it's condition is met**, they may first execute something and then **return something (exiting the function and not allowing to move to a second if statement)**. This kind of if statement is called a guard clause. If however the **first guard clause's condition is not met**, **it will continue through the function to the next guard clause and so on if there are more guard clauses** until the end. The maybe slightly tricky thing about guard clauses is if you are going to have more than one, they need to be in the right order. The order goes from independent to dependent. E.g. if you have a function which takes a parameter `password` and you want to do some checks on it, you can only check if the password is too short after knowing a password was entered in the first place. And so your first guard clause in this case would need to check if a password was **not** entered. If a password was not entered (`password == "" || null`), the return statement is used to immediately exit the function and not allow to continue execution onto the second guard clause. This needs to happen because the second guard clause checks if the password is too short and it can only do so if a password was entered in the first place. **The second guard clause depends on the first**. If you had a third guard clause which checked if the password was too long, **it would also depend on the first guard clause and it would depend on the second guard clause as well**. For example, if a password's length is less than 4 characters, you don't need to go to the third guard clause to check if the password's length is over 20 characters. At the end of our function (after all our guard clauses), we return something which will only be reached if all the guard clause's conditions were not met. E.g, in the password example, if a password **was** entered, the password **was** 4 or more characters long and the password **was** under 20 characters long, we may return a string such as, `"valid password"`.

**Another Example**

Lets say you have a function to check if a user can make an account. The function takes two parameters, `canMakeAccount(name, password) {...}`. It checks the two parameters are valid with guard clauses. The first guard clause checks if `name` and/or `pass` are `""` (a field was left blank). If this condition was met, the function is exited with the `return` keyword. The function will return an object:

```
return {
    accountCanBeMade: false, 
    message: "Fields cannot be left blank :("
}
```

**However**, if the condition **was not** met (all fields were filled out), then the program continues through the function, going through two more guard clauses and checking if `name` is too long or `password` is too short. Again, if one of these guard clause's conditions are met, a similar return statement is executed, just that the message property in the object is different.

**See below example**

```
function canMakeAccount(name, pass) {
    // if name or pass are empty strings
    if (name == null || name == "" || pass == null || pass == "") {
        return {
            accountCanBeMade: false,
            message: "Fields cannot be left blank :("
        }
    }

    // if name is too long
    if (name.length > 10) {
        return {
            accountCanBeMade: false,
            message: "Username is over 10 characters :("
        }
    }

    // if password is too short
    if (pass.length < 4) {
        return {
            accountCanBeMade: false,
            message: "Password is less than 4 characters :("
        }
    }

    // if everything is filled out correctly
    // (all fields filled, name not too long, pass not too short)
    return {
        accountCanBeMade: true,
        message: "Have a nice day"
    }
}
```

with the above example, if **name was "Jacob123and456"** and **pass was "12"**, calling the function returns:

```
const nameVariable = "Jacob123and456";
const passVariable = "12";

const details = canMakeAccount(nameVariable, passVariable);

// 'details' returns
//
// => {
//     accountCanBeMade: false, 
//     message: "Username is over 10 characters :("
// }
```

**Snippet of the full above example:**

```js
const inpName = document.querySelector("input#inp-name");
const inpPass = document.querySelector("input#inp-pass");
const btnCheck = document.querySelector("button");
const pInfo = document.querySelector("p#info");

function canMakeAccount(name, pass) {
    // if a field was left blank
    if (name == null || name == "" || pass == null || pass == "") {
        return {
            accountCanBeMade: false,
            message: "Fields cannot be left blank :("
        }
    }

    // if name is too long
    if (name.length > 10) {
        return {
            accountCanBeMade: false,
            message: "Username is over 10 characters :("
        }
    }

    // if password is too short
    if (pass.length < 4) {
        return {
            accountCanBeMade: false,
            message: "Password is less than 4 characters :("
        }
    }

    // if everything is filled out correctly
    return {
        accountCanBeMade: true,
        message: "Have a nice day"
    }
}

btnCheck.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const data = canMakeAccount(inpName.value, inpPass.value);

    let text = "";

    // if user has filled out everything correctly
    if (data.accountCanBeMade) text += "<strong>You can make your account!</strong> :)<br>";
    // else (if a field was empty or name was too long or password was too short)
    else text += "<strong>You can't make your account! </strong> :(<br>";

    // write dots
    text += "<strong>...</strong><br><br>";

    // write message
    text += data.message;

    // show text in the page
    pInfo.innerHTML = text;
});
```

```css
input, button {
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Username" id="inp-name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter a Password" id="inp-pass">
    <button>Can I make my account?</button>
    <br>
    <p id="info"></p>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```